# How to write into XMl at a particular node in android?

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing

I have a XML file like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Survey 
Name="Aerosmith's Survey" 
Id="S2"
UserId="Admin"
CreatedBy="Administrator"
cultureName="en-CA" 
numberOfQuestions="5"
completedPercent="0" 
createdTimeStamp="June 26, 2012 16:01" 
lastUpdatedTimeStamp="">
<Questions>
<Question
    id="q1"
    name="Question #1" 
    type="SingleChoice" 
    allowBackButton="false" 
    isRequired="true" 
    numLines="0" 
    questionIndex="1">
        <QuestionText>Who is your favourite Aerosmith's Member ?</QuestionText>
        <Answers>
            <Answer answerIndex="1" >Joey Kramer</Answer>
            <Answer answerIndex="2" >Steven Tyler</Answer>
            <Answer answerIndex="3" >Tom Hamilton</Answer>
            <Answer answerIndex="4" >Joe Perry</Answer>
            <Answer answerIndex="4" >Brad Whitford</Answer>
        </Answers>
        <Response respondedTimeStamp=""></Response>
        <OnChoice></OnChoice>
    </Question>
    <Question 
        id="q2"
        name="Question #2" 
        type="MultipleChoice" 
        allowBackButton="true" 
        isRequired="true" 
        numLines="0" 
        questionIndex="2">
        <QuestionText> Which is your favourite Aerosmith Song ?</QuestionText>
        <Answers>
            <Answer answerIndex="1" >Dream On</Answer>
            <Answer answerIndex="2" >Sweet Emotion</Answer>
            <Answer answerIndex="3" >Walk this way!!</Answer>
            <Answer answerIndex="4" >I Don't Want to Miss a Thing</Answer>
            <Answer answerIndex="5" >Jaded</Answer>
        </Answers>
        <Response respondedTimeStamp=""></Response>
        <OnChoice></OnChoice>
    </Question>
    <Question 
        id="q3"
        name="Question #3" 
        type="Date" 
        allowBackButton="true" 
        isRequired="true" 
        numLines="0" 
        questionIndex="3">
        <QuestionText>What is Your Date of birth?</QuestionText>
        <Answers></Answers>
        <Response respondedTimeStamp=""></Response>
        <OnChoice></OnChoice>
    </Question>
</Questions>
</Survey>
```

Now in my App I have used a SAX parser to read these.
Now each question has a question type as you can see in my xml.

```
<Question
    id="q1"
    name="Question #1" 
    type="SingleChoice" 
    allowBackButton="false" 
    isRequired="true" 
    numLines="0" 
    questionIndex="1">
```

based on this I have populated my Checkbox in a list view.

Now what i want to do is that suppose any user checks an item then in the tag

```
<Response respondedTimeStamp=""></Response>
```

I have to write the time stamp and the response value as text for that particular question.

So How do i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **[XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/%20XStream)** library for writing the data to the xml.

Comment: ok Xstream looks good,  but I was searching for something for which I dont have to go outside java/android or use any external library (like xstream) in your case, basically I need to search for that element and write value in that.!!